# error in time validation

Tags: c#

i have a textbox which is determining the time, on the form load i have written the code so that the time will be filled in the textbox which is in this format
09:09 AM
i am using the regex for validation purpose
so i have wirtten this code

```
private bool time()
{
  Regex regex = new Regex("^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$");
  if (regex.IsMatch(textBox2.Text))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

there is a button in the form which is for showing if the error is there then the error provider shows the error, and if not, then error provider doesnt blink, the code for button click is

the problem is when i keep the textbox blank and clicks the button, the error provider doesnt shows the error
even if i put ''09:09 st'' instead of ''09:09 pm'' it doesnt shows error  but my regex is wright

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your logic on backwards.

If the regex matches, you return `true` and set the error message. I guess it should be the other way around.

Also, try to give your methods (and form elements) more meaningful names like:

```
private bool CheckTimeFormat(string value)
{
  Regex regex = new Regex("^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$");
  return regex.IsMatch(value);
}

private void SetInvalidTimeFormatError()
{
  bool isValidTime = CheckTimeFormat(textBox2.Text);
  if (isValidTime)
  {
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2, string.Empty);
  }
  else
  {
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2, "invalid format");
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you do if you put your underwear on backwards? :D

Answer (score 0):

You dont' really need regexes for such a validation.

```
private bool time() {
    DateTime input;
    return DateTime.TryParse(textbox2.text, out input);
}
```

You might want to play a bit with more advanced version of `TryParse` to explicitly specify datetime format you expect.

See MSDN for detailed description:

1. [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wteydsd6.aspx)
2. [`DateTime.TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9h21f14e.aspx)

Also you might want to give some meaningful names to your functions, like `IsValidDateTime`.

Comment: i have my own validation can you guide me where is my mistake? i want to face that, where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think blank is not checked in the textbox.
In your time() function
check by giving the following condition:

```
if(textBox2.Text=="")
return false;
```

thanks.

Comment: no its not... if i put '09:09 st'' instead of ''09:09 pm'' its is not showing error, and my regex is perfect